# Controlling parent element based on child input:focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<div>` element containing a `<form>` element with an `<input>` field. This div also contain a `<button>` that is hidden via overflow:hidden.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1D1.jpg)

When a user click on the input field, its height will change, and the overflow:hidden will become overflow:visible. The first effect I can achieve with input:focus, but I am having problem with the second targeting the parent . I understand that selector can't ascend in CSS3, so I tried to use jQuery has() function, but it doesn't seem to work (probably entirely my fault).

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
  $("div:has(input:focus)").addClass("visible");
</script>
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? What can I do to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: `$("input:focus").closest("div")` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  $(this).parents('div').css({"overflow":"visible" });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm also trying to target the parent <div> -- doesn't this just target the input itself?

Comment: you mean you need to make the div as overflow:visible? check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try to access the parent element using jQuery `parent()`

```
var input = $('input');
input.on('focus', function(e) {
    var form = input.parent();
    var div = form.parent()[0];
    // Do your css customization here
});
```

You can also try to use `closest()` method

```
var input = $('input');
input.on('focus', function(e) {
    var div = input.closest('div');
    // Do your css customization here
});
```

Personally I prefer `closest()` method but it is good to know another way.